# SharePoint view with 2900 records throwing 5000 limit error

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint, linked-list

I have a list that resides on SharePoint 2013 and we manage the records in The list using MS Access 2016.  Basic add, remove, update to match stuff to an excel file we are provided twice per month.

I am running into the 5000 record error on list views with active filters that only have say 2900 records meeting the criteria.

If I query for the same filters in access I get the 2900 and the list only has 5200 total records.

I am looking for any direction of things to look for or articles to read that may help point me in the right direction of what may be causing this.

Thank you very n advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

What i have experienced with this is that if you have multiple conditions in your filter, and one of them returns over 4999 items you will get that error. What i have done in my case is to add conditions to my filter that use indexed columns to help initially limit the number of items result based on the indexed column.

For example, in my scenario, I had a filter that was based on the workflow status and the current user. But my filter initially did not use an indexed column and the condition "Status eq 'Approved'" returned over 5000 items.

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Approvals')/items?$filter=Status eq 'Completed' and Author/EMail eq 'user@contoso.com'
```

Changing the query to use the indexed AuthorId column, resolved my issue.

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Approvals')/items?$filter=AuthorId eq 1234 and Status eq 'Completed'
```

Comment: Thank you for the feed back.  In this situation I have one column that is indexed which splits the 5200 records into A 2900 and B 2300.  If I set the filter for B it works, but A causes the error.